# Gerrit 3.0.4 replication faild due to Auth fail

Tags: authentication, gitlab, replication, gerrit

I'm running gerrit in docker, but now I can not replicate commits to our private gitlab server.

Here's my replication.config

```
[remote "git.server.com"]
        url = url = git@git.server.com:my-group/${name}.git
        push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
        push = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
        push = +refs/changes/*:refs/changes/*
        threads = 3
        rescheduleDelay = 15

[replication]
        maxRetries = 1

[gerrit]
        autoReload = true
        replicateOnStartup = true
```

here's the /var/gerrit/.ssh/config:

```
Host git.server.com:
        User git
        StrictHostKeyChecking no
        UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        PreferredAuthentications publickey
```

And replication_log outputs:

```
[2019-12-20 10:58:04,914] [a23c87d1] Push to git@git.server.com:my-group/All-Projects.git cancelled after maximum number of retries
[2019-12-20 10:58:32,606] [0220f3d3] Replication to git@git.server.com:my-group/All-Users.git started...
[2019-12-20 10:58:33,036] [0220f3d3] Cannot replicate to git@git.server.com:my-group/All-Users.git
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: git@git.server.com:my-group/All-Users.git: Auth fail
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:170)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.listRemote(PushOne.java:595)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.doPushAll(PushOne.java:534)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.generateUpdates(PushOne.java:523)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.pushVia(PushOne.java:464)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.runImpl(PushOne.java:454)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.runPushOperation(PushOne.java:338)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.lambda$run$0(PushOne.java:299)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator.lambda$cleanup$1(RequestScopePropagator.java:182)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator.lambda$context$0(RequestScopePropagator.java:170)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.git.PerThreadRequestScope$Propagator.lambda$scope$0(PerThreadRequestScope.java:70)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.run(PushOne.java:302)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.logging.LoggingContextAwareRunnable.run(LoggingContextAwareRunnable.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.git.WorkQueue$Task.run(WorkQueue.java:610)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:145)
```

I already add /var/gerrit/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to our private gitlab server(SSH Key). I add a issue [here](https://github.com/openfrontier/docker-gerrit/issues/123) too.

Comment: Can you try to SSH from the container where Gerrit is running to your gitlab server with the same keys used by the replication plugin to make sure SSH is working?

Comment: @barbasa Thanks for you reply, but that's not the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the gerrit server from the [openfrontier](https://hub.docker.com/r/openfrontier/gerrit) docker image and encountered these problems, but after a few days of searching, I finally re-created the gerrit server from the [gerritcodereview](https://hub.docker.com/r/gerritcodereview/gerrit) docker image, and now everything works fine.

I compared the docker images in [gerritcodereview](https://hub.docker.com/r/gerritcodereview/gerrit) and [openfrontier](https://hub.docker.com/r/openfrontier/gerrit), and there are many differences. With [openfrontier](https://hub.docker.com/r/openfrontier/gerrit), the container default user is root, and they created some scripts before gerrit is started, and the gerrit user is non-loginable, you must use scripts to handle gerrit stuff.

The official Gerrit docker image is [gerritcodereview](https://hub.docker.com/r/gerritcodereview/gerrit), and the default user of the container is gerrit, just like a normal gerrit server. I can configure everything myself.